# SpinnerButtonAdapter using ASyncTask to auto select from database

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a spinner which is populated from the database. This in turn is pulled from a webservice so it is not possible to hard-code the values.

The spinner is part of a form that the user fills out and saves and I need them to be able to go back in and edit the values, so I am trying to auto-populate it based on what was selected.

The problem is that the spinner does not always select, which happens more often than not. I think this is due to the fact that I am loading the data asynchronously using an asynctask, and by the time it retrieves the data the spinner has yet not been loaded. I have logging showing that, for example, spinner item 4 was pulled from the database, but the spinner shows nothing selected.

What is the best way to find out when the loader has been completed so that I can populate (ie select) the relevant item in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the call at the end of the load finished method,

```
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> aLoader, Cursor aCursor) {
        int id = aLoader.getId();

        Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader = null;
        switch (id) {
            mAdapter.swapCursor(aCursor);
        }
        if (inEditMode) {
            fillInValues();
        }
    }
```